# Find the best (and easiest) way to merge multiple .xml files into one

Tags: xml

I'm updating an old flash site where all contents were published with .xml files. I have a structure like this:

/projects.xml that contains all references to children files like /en/project_1.xml and /fr/project_2.xml … /en/project_n.xml and /fr/project_n.xml. You get the idea.

What I need to do is to merge all this structure into **one** .xml file, to be able then to import into my CMS.

Here follows a better explanation of what every file contains:

the main file (the one I will process later) projects.xml

```
 <project some_data="" link="reference_link.xml" />
 <project some_data="" link="reference_link_2.xml" />
```

note that **link="reference_link.xml"** is a pointer to the single .xml project file.

here one of the single project_n.xml files:

```
<project >
    <data project_data="" >
        <copy description="single project data here" />
    </data>
</project>
```

So, what am I trying to get? Easy, a new projects.xml that contains all his references; something like that:

```
<project some_data="" link="reference_link.xml" en_description="single project data here" fr_description="single project data here" en_project_data="" fr_project_data="" />
<project some_data="" link="reference_link_2.xml" en_description="single project data here" fr_description="single project data here" en_project_data="" fr_project_data="" />
...
```

Have you any idea on how can I achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: What scripting or programming languages do you know?

Comment: mh, I'm just thinking about writing a simple javascript app and run it locally, then print out a pre-formatted html page and copy all the text from there... sounds good?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: nothing right now, but the more I think about it, the more seems easier to do... just wonder... I have something like 200/250 xml files to parse, will this crash the browser? I never made so many calls, I'm using a browser to do something that was it not intended to...

Comment: ...only one way to find out: try it.